# how to count spaces of a list in python?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, string, list

I have a list that the total number of spaces between words should be counted.
For example:
`vocab = ['he llo','go ing','home work','play foot ball','spring']`

The count of spaces here should be 5.

I use this code but it counts the space of only the last words in the list:

```
x  = sum(c.isspace() for c in vocab)
```

Could you help me, please?

Comment: `v == vocab`...?

Comment: Sorry.. I named my list wrong. My list name is Vocab.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a Counter like this in a loop,

```
from collections import Counter

sum(Counter(x).get(" ", 0) for x in v) # 5
```

If you are worried about repeated Counter call, you can join all the strings and use a single Counter call

```
Counter("".join(v)).get(" ") # 5
```

As suggested by @superb rain, joining all the strings and using count method will be good for your use case. If you need count of more strings in one go, you can use Counter based solution.

```
"".join(v).count(" ")
```

Comment: maybe if someone need to count more than one item? For example get count of space and string "a" in one go. Other than that, I think count method will be better to go for

Answer (score 2):

You need two loops to iterate over a word and the list of words:

```
v=['he llo','go ing','home work','play foot ball','spring']
x  = sum(c.isspace() for vocab in v for c in vocab)
print(x)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) and [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.findall) to count the number of **whitespace**:

```
import re
vocab = ['he llo','go ing','home work','play foot ball','spring']
num_whitespace = len([w for s in vocab for w in re.findall(r'\s', s)])
print(num_whitespace)
# 5
```

Answer (score 1):

You can count spaces in each string and sum() the total:

```
sum(s.count(" ") for s in vocab)  # 5
```